# UICollectionView Cell didSelectItemAt not called

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use 2 different collectionview in UIViewController

Problem is when I press the first `collectionView` at that time the call goes in didselectItem, but when I press the other collectionviewcell its not called.

Below is my code:-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == participantsCollectionView {
        print("participant")
    } else {
        print("image")
    }    
}
```

Layout Setting

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 72, height: 72)
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

let frame = CGRect(x: 24, y: 766, width: 326, height: 156)
eventImagesCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
eventImagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
eventImagesCollectionView.delegate = self

let imagesNib = UINib(nibName: "EventImagesCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
eventImagesCollectionView.register(imagesNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
eventImagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.contentView.addSubview(eventImagesCollectionView)
self.contentView.removeConstraints(self.stackView.constraints)
eventImagesCollectionView <- [
    Top(24).to(self.stackView),
    Left(24),
    Right(24),
    Width(326),
    Height(156),
]
eventImagesCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Second Collection View

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 36, height: 36)
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 433, width: 352, height: 36)
participantsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
participantsCollectionView.dataSource = self
participantsCollectionView.delegate = self

let nib = UINib(nibName: "EventParticipantsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
participantsCollectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
participantsCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.contentView.addSubview(participantsCollectionView)

self.eventDescriptionLabel <- [
    Top(12).to(self.eventTitleLabel)
]
participantsCollectionView <- [
    Top(12).to(self.eventDescriptionLabel),
    Left(0),
    Right(24),
    Width(351),
    Height(36),
]
participantsCollectionView.easy_reload()

let goingButtonFrame = CGRect(x: 103, y: 485, width: 88, height: 29)
let goingButton = UIButton(frame: goingButtonFrame)
var colors = [UIColor(hex: "F65557"), UIColor(hex: "FA8C35")]
goingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(gradientStyle: .leftToRight, withFrame: goingButton.frame, andColors: colors)
goingButton.tintColor = .white
goingButton.setTitle("Going", for: .normal)
let verifyImage = UIImage(named: "ic_done_black_24px")
goingButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Brandon_reg", size: 15)
goingButton.cornerRadius = 4
goingButton.setImage(verifyImage, for: .normal)
self.contentView.addSubview(goingButton)

goingButton <- [
    Top(12).to(participantsCollectionView),
    Width(88),
    Height(29),
    Left(103)
]

let inviteButtonFrame = CGRect(x: 203, y: 485, width: 70, height: 29)
let inviteButton = UIButton(frame: inviteButtonFrame)
inviteButton.borderColor = UIColor(hex: "FF6F5F")
inviteButton.borderWidth = 1
inviteButton.backgroundColor = .clear

inviteButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: "FF6F5F"), for: .normal)
inviteButton.setTitle("Invite", for: .normal)

inviteButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Brandon_reg", size: 15)
inviteButton.cornerRadius = 4
inviteButton.setImage(verifyImage, for: .normal)
self.contentView.addSubview(inviteButton)

inviteButton <- [
    Top(12).to(participantsCollectionView),
    Width(70),
    Height(29),
    Right(102),
    Left(12).to(goingButton)
]

self.stackView <- [
    Top(12).to(goingButton),
    Left(0),
    Right(0)
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that you set `collectionView.delegate = self` for both `UICollectionView`?

Comment: yes I am sure about it

Comment: Can you add that part?

Comment: May be its because you have not added 'participantsCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true' in your second collectionView

Comment: @Ishika no I tried it too

Comment: Can you share this project so I can look around?

Comment: @Ryan I already share the code.

Comment: Do u find the right answer? @thelethalcoder